# How can I keep AWS-SDK gem from trying to run .load_yaml_config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, initialization, aws-sdk

I am working on an old-ish codebase that supports connections to many different databases. I am trying to create a new environment so I can open a `rails console` with a connection to the particular database that I need to use for the part of the application I'm working on. The name of the environment is `nhl_development`.

So far, I've created a new config file and added relevant database config:

```
# database.yml

generic: &generic
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 30

dev_default: &dev_default
  <<: *generic
  host: <%= ENV['FOO']%>
  username: <%= ENV['BAR']%>
  password: <%= ENV['BAZ']%>
  pool: 30

nhl_development:
  <<: *dev_default
  database: nhl

# config/environments/nhl_development.rb

Stats::Application.configure do
  # copied entirely from config/environments/development.rb
end
```

When I run `rails c nhl_development` from my command line, I get the following error from the `AWS-SDK` gem:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.60.2/lib/aws/rails.rb:110:in `load_yaml_config': config/aws.yml is missing a section for `nhl_development` (RuntimeError)
...
...
from /home/me/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I understand the basic point of this error message. When I open `config/aws.yml` there is no set of config for `nhl_development`. However, what I don't understand is:

Where is `AWS::Rails.load_yaml_config` being called? I don't think I even want/need AWS to load configuration in this environment. The stack trace leads back to `config/environment.rb:5` but that's just the line that initializes the Rails app. There is no initializer for AWS in `config/initializers` and I've done a find-in-project for `.load_yaml_config` with no results. I can get everything working by adding a section of config for this environment in `config/aws.yml` but I don't to load any AWS config at this time. How can I keep `AWS::Rails.load_yaml_config` from being called in this environment so that I don't have to mess with `config/aws.yml` right now??

Comment: I think rails loads all of the gems on startup, including when running rails c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the gem itself that does this. When it is required (which bundles will do if it is in your Gemfile) it loads [this file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/aws-sdk-v1/lib/aws/rails.rb) which registers an initializer that (among other things) calls `load_yaml_config`.

You could conceivably solve this by tuning off autorequire for that one gem (`require: false`) in your Gemfile and ensuring that the gem isn't loaded by any other means until after initialisers have run but that sounds a bit hacky. I think the easiest way is just to add an entry to that yaml file